# Iterate through a list in Facelets

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, drop-down-menu, iteration, facelets

I have this code

```
<select id="vlm" name="vlm" class="pnx-inline-edit-select">
    <option value="#{agreement.valueForNiVlmVersion}">
        <h:outputText value="#{agreement.valueForNiVlmVersion}"/>
    </option>
</select>
```

This displays a dropdown box with the content of valueForNiVlmVersion. Now, in that same bean, I have a list of values called validValues that needs to be displayed there instead of a single valueForNiVlmVersion. **So, I need to remove the valueForNiVlmVersion and instead, add the values from validValues.** The thing is that I'm not sure how to iterate through a list to pull the values dynamically. I can use javascript and jquery 1.9.

Thanks!

Comment: Surely it's easily possible, but is there any particular reason why you can't just use JSF-provided `<h:selectOneMenu><f:selectItems>`? See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info

Comment: Originally, there was a slight restriction, but after seeing the post you mentioned, I found a way to use it as mentioned in the post. Thanks!

Comment: Okay. Skuntsel completed the question anyway by showing the right "plain HTML" iteration approach. Take your pick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an iterative component for this purpose like `<ui:repeat>`, to produce custom HTML code in a way you like:

```
<select id="vlm" name="vlm" class="pnx-inline-edit-select">
    <ui:repeat value="#{bean.validValues}" var="val">
        <option value="#{val.value}">#{val.label}</option>
    </ui:repeat>
</select>
```

But ultimately, why are you not considering a standard [`<h:selectOneMenu>`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info) solution?